# Handle bar - Iterate through JSON array

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON Array as shown below using a handle bar code.

JSON array:

```
[{"email":"zzz@g.com","repo":"https://github.com"},{"email":"xxx@g.com","repo":"https://github.com"},{"email":"yyy@g.com","repo":"https://github.com"}]
```

Handle bar code:

```
{{#each ["abc"].[json]}}
       EMAIL:{{["abc"].[json].[@index].[email]}}
       REPO:{{["abc"].[json].[@index].[repo]}}
       {{#if @last }}
           Last entry!
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

where ["abc"].[json].[0...100].email/repo is the output Json array from a previous process. With the code above I'm not getting the required result and the output are empty strings, any help is much appreciated.

Required OUTPUT:

```
EMAIL:zzz@g.com
REPO:https://github.com
EMAIL:xxx@g.com
REPO:https://github.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `#each` helper the context switch to the current element, similar as in a forEach method in JS:

```
{{#each ["abc"].[json]}}
   EMAIL:{{email}}
   REPO:{{repo}}
   {{#if @last }}
       Last entry!
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```